# Adjoining element in a finite field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ to $\mathbb F_p$ to get $\mathbb F_{p^6}$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Given that $p$ is a prime and $n$ is a natural number, I want to know how many $\alpha$ are in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ such that $\mathbb F_p (\alpha) = \mathbb F_{p^6}$.

I know that $[\mathbb F_{p^6} : \mathbb F_p] = 6$, so $\mathbb F_p (\alpha) = \mathbb F_{p^6}$ would happen if and only if the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p$ has a degree of $6$, but not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

To long for a comment, let me know if there are mistakes in my argument.

For $a,b\in \mathbb N$ it holds $\mathbb F_{p^a} \subset \mathbb F_{p^b} \Leftrightarrow a|b$, so if $n$ is not a multiple of $6$ the field $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ is not contained in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

If $n$ is a multiple of $6$, fix an algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb F}$ of $\mathbb F_p$. The elements of $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ are exaclty the roots of $X^{p^n}-X\in \mathbb F[X]$ in $\bar{\mathbb F}$,  and the elements of $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ are exaclty the roots of $X^{p^6}-X$. So the elements $\alpha\in \mathbb F_{p^n}$ generating for $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ are the elements in this field which are not contained in a proper subfield: $\mathbb F_{p}$, $ \mathbb F_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb F_{p^3}$, therefore there are
$$p^6-(p^3-p)-(p^2-p)-p= p^6-p^3-p^2+p$$
generating elements, since $\mathbb F_{p^3}\cap \mathbb F_{p^2}= \mathbb F_{p}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more for the last sentence?

Comment: The answer is right: accords with the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @QuinMorris $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ has $p^6$ elements and we have to remove the elements contained in $\mathbb F_{p}$,  in $\mathbb F_{p^3}\setminus \mathbb F_{p}$ (we already removed the elements in $\mathbb F_{p}$)  and  in $\mathbb F_{p^2}\setminus \mathbb F_{p}$.

Comment: @Desperado So each element of $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ that are not contained in its subfield generates $\mathbb F_{p^6}$? Does it follow from that $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ is cyclic, and every elements of order 2 and 3 generate smaller fields, and rest are of order 6?

Comment: @QuinMorris: More or less. The minimalpolynomial $f$ of an element $a\in \mathbb F_{p^6}$ over $\mathbb F_{p}$ has degree $d:=\deg(f)$ a divisor of $6=|\mathbb F_{p^6}: \mathbb F_{p}|$, by the degree formula,  since you have a chain of extensions $\mathbb F_{p^6}- \mathbb F_{p}(a) -\mathbb F_{p}$.

If $a$ is in a subfield then $d<6$ and conversely if $d<6$, then $\mathbb F_p(a) \cong\mathbb  F_{p^d} \neq \mathbb  F_{p^6}$.